# Creating Email Template in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, html-email

I am trying to create EmailTemplates. I have been able to write the controller codes and also created a .txt file in a folder but when the mail is been sent, the users receive it as a HTML code.

**Controller code**

```
   public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email, 
                                            Firstname = model.Firstname, Surname = model.Surname, Gender = model.Gender};
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                string body = string.Empty;
                var root = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory; using (var reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(root + @"/EmailTemplates/ConfirmAccount.txt"))
                {
                    string readFile = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    string StrContent = string.Empty;
                    StrContent = readFile;
                    //Assing the field values in the template
                    StrContent = StrContent.Replace("[Firstname]", user.Firstname);
                    StrContent = StrContent.Replace("[Surname]", user.Surname);
                    StrContent = StrContent.Replace("[Code]", callbackUrl);
                    StrContent = StrContent.Replace("[Year]", DateTime.Now.Year.ToString());
                    body = StrContent.ToString();
                }
                await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm Your Account", body);
 return View("DisplayEmail");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        
        return View(model);
    }
```

**Below is the .txt file content**

```
<!doctype html>     
<html lang="tr">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>     
 <body>
   <p>Dear [Firstname]  [Surname],</p>
   <p>Kindly Confirm your Email by clicking the link below</p>
   <p>[Code]</p>
 </body>
```

The output is in form of a HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The better way to send HTML formatted Email your code will be in "ConfirmAccount.htm"

```
<!doctype html>     
<html lang="tr">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 </head>     
 <body>
   <p>Dear [Firstname]  [Surname],</p>
   <p>Kindly Confirm your Email by clicking the link below</p>
   <p>[Code]</p>
 </body>
```

Read HTML file Using System.IO.File.ReadAllText. get all HTML code in string variable.

```
string Body = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("EmailTemplates/ConfirmAccount.htm"));
```

Replace a Particular string with your custom value.

```
Body = Body.Replace("[Firstname]", user.Firstname);
```

Call SendEmail(string Body) Function and do a procedure to send an email.
Replace the Session email and Configuration app settings with your ones.

```
public static void SendEmail(string Body)
        {
            MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
            message.From = new MailAddress(Session["Email"].Tostring());
            message.To.Add(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["RequesEmail"].ToString());
            message.Subject = "Request from " + SessionFactory.CurrentCompany.CompanyName + " to add a new supplier";
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            message.Body = Body;

            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
            smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

            smtpClient.Host = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["SMTP"].ToString();
            smtpClient.Port = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["PORT"].ToString());
            smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
            smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["USERNAME"].ToString(), ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["PASSWORD"].ToString());
            smtpClient.Send(message);
        }
```

You can check out in `message.IsBodyHtml = true` SendEmailAsyn Method

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have a SendEmail function already. Can I have a full code to use this "Body = Body.Replace("[Firstname]", user.Firstname);" ?

Comment: Please note that I have attempted using ConfirmAccount.htm with my above Controller Code

Comment: Is it to false or to true?

Comment: Thank you Waleed. In my SendEmailAsync, I added the message.IsBodyHtml = true and also made use of the ConfirmAccount.htm.  It works well now. Can you edit the answer for me to accept?